# Weblogic 12c web service generates null pointer exception on deployment

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

When upgrading to weblogic 12c from 10.3 we are getting the following null pointer exception on deployment for our web service. The same web service works fine in weblogic 10.3. I am using wsgen to build the webservice. I am also using java 1.7, but have tried the same with 1.6

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.addSchemaComponents(SchemaGenerator.java:206)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.generateSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:144)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.generateSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Generator.java:209)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.generateSchema(JAXBContext.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.generateSchema(JAXBContext.java:215)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextWrapper.generateSchema(JAXBContextWrapper.java:116)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.generateTypes(WSDLGenerator.java:433)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.generateDocument(WSDLGenerator.java:409)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.doGeneration(WSDLGenerator.java:306)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.generateWSDL(DatabindingImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.generateWSDL(EndpointFactory.java:528)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:240)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:525)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:257)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:151)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:582)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:233)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:190)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:175)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1730)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:192)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:369)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:186)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:94)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: have you found answer for this question ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and discovered that I had included two (2) Weblogic 10 files in my WAR file which cause this issue; weblogic-10.3.6.jar and wlfullclient-10.3.6.jar.

Once I removed the, it started up fine.